# How to return interface list from a for loop in Go?

Tags: go

How to return interface list from a for loop in Go?
Supposed I have data as below:

| id | name | project_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | project_name | 1 |
| 2 | project_name | 1 |
| 3 | project_name | 1 |
| 4 | project_name | 2 |
| 5 | project_name | 2 |
| 6 | project_name | 3 |
| 7 | project_name | 3 |
| 8 | project_name | 3 |
| 9 | project_name | 4 |
| 10 | project_name | 4 |

I can use the below go code to get two list of project_type=1 and project_type=2,

```golang
func (d *db) ProjectList(Type, uid string, size uint64) (interface{}, interface{}, error) {
    type resp struct {
        Name            string  `json:"name"`
        Id             string  `json:"id"`
        ProjectType    string  `json:"project_type"`

    }

    var project_type_1 []*resp
    var project_type_2 []*resp

    sql = fmt.Sprintf(sql, where.String())
    _, err := d.ctx.DB().SelectBySql("select * from project where project_type=1 order by rand() limit 10").Load(&project_type_1)

    _, err = d.ctx.DB().SelectBySql("select * from project where project_type=2 order by rand() limit 10").Load(&project_type_2)
    return project_type_1, project_type_2, err
}
```

But now the data of project_type is a JSON of `[{"project_type":1,"name":"something else"},{"project_type":2,"name":"something else"},{"project_type":3,"name":"something else"},{"project_type":4,"name":"something else"}]`, project_type is more than 2, I have to get a interface{} list, I tried to re-write code as below, But I don't know how do write next, How to return interface list from a for loop in Go?, thanks so much for any advice.

```golang
func NewProjectList(d *db) ([]interface{}, error) {
    var s = make([]ProjectType, 0)
    data, err := d.QueryString("project_type")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &s)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, shortType := range s {
        fmt.Println("this is shortType", shortType)
    }
    return nil, err

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a single query that has a `project_type=1 OR project_type=2` condition in the where clause?

Comment: @mkopriva I need to return 4 lists or more than 4 lists to front-end

Comment: @mkopriva more than 4 interface{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want each project_type have 10 results(all 10*n results):

```
func (d *db) ProjectList(Type, uid string, size uint64) ([]interface{}, error) {
    type resp struct {
        Name        string `json:"name"`
        Id          string `json:"id"`
        ProjectType string `json:"project_type"`
    }
    // get all types, you can get it from db
    // example: select DISTINCT ProjectType from project
    types := []string{"1", "2", "3", "4"}
    ans := []interface{}{}

    for _, sType := range types {
        var project_type []*resp
        sql = fmt.Sprintf(sql, where.String())
        _, err := d.ctx.DB().SelectBySql("select * from project where project_type=" + sType + " order by rand() limit 10").Load(&project_type)
        ans = append(ans, project_type)
    }
    return ans, nil
}
```

if A total of 10 results for all types:

```
 i write it if you need it
```

Comment: hi, thanks so much for your answer, you saved my day!!!  Can I define the types before append? Return such as: `{"data_of_1":[], "data_of_2":[],"data_of_3":[]}`

Comment: of course you can, return map[string] []*resp